http only cookie alternative in react native
i have got web project using mern stack where i store the jwt as an http only cookie, so that when user authenticates themselves, it is not required to pass the token as a header.
however, i will also be building the mobile version of this project in the future using react native, as http only cookie system doesnt work for the mobile, what can i do now?
is storing jwt in the localstorage and passing it in the header the only alternative? or are there other ways where i could still use http only cookie system in the web, and use some other alternatives for app, and still have the same backend overall. looking for the feedbacks and guidance

Can you describe what is not working ? Why can't just use lcoalstorage ?
